# No VT-X support for Intel i7-4702MQ as required by a virtual machine ? How to enable?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I've recently bought a brand new machine from Clevo. It has the i7-4702MQ CPU from Intel and should be used for development, where sometimes a virtual machine is necessary.

However, I can't seem to enable VT-X in BIOS - I've checked everywhere and there is no option.

The following document from Intel shows that VT-X might be disabled by the vendor ? Does this mean that I can't ever enable this setting ? Is there a workaround ? I really need to run a virtual machine ...

http://ark.intel.com/products/75119/Intel-Core-i7-4702MQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz

CPU-Z image of CPU-specifications:

[image]

Comment: If there is no option in the firmware to enable it, the it cannot be enabled, not a great deal you can do about it. You do understand that extension isn't required for a virtual machine right, just makes it easier, more things are possible if it does

Comment: Why on earth would a company choose to disable a feature when it is available in the CPU ?

Comment: Perhaps to sell another model which does have it enabled for a higher price?

Comment: The CPU itself supports it.  Contact the OEM if you want to knowing there is some way to enable it